# Should an Entity Framework DbContext run under a less privileged user than migrations?

Tags: database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, database-migration

### Two ways

For EF Core, I have often seen the suggestion to run the migrations as part of the startup process of the application.

For our web application at work, we have a separate application which runs our migrations. The web application itself runs under a different user, who does not have the rights to change the schema.

### My considerations

- It *does* prevent SQL injection changing the schema.
- That work application is 15+ years old. Modern ORMs have gotten pretty good at preventing SQL injection.
- It prevents SQL injection from outright dropping a column, but using the allowed operations to fill the column with garbage data seems about equally destructive.

### Question

For an EF Core project, under which circumstances is such a separation necessary/advisable/still worth it?

Comment: Do you want to ask about the scenario of data migration with root authority?

Comment: @Chaodeng I don't think so; I'm talking about the rights given to a user by SQL Server. If I understand correctly, that _can_ be the OS root. However, the point is about having the application run under a user - _any user_ - who does not have the right to execute e.g. the SQL command DROP.

Comment: Is it the same as the example mentioned in this official document?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15